# Extract value of variable to local macro if condition is met

Tags: stata

I frequently write for-loops that accomplish the following:

1. Cycle through values of a row identifier like household number
2. Extract information about that household from other variables
3. Save that information in a local macro

Right now the way I do this seems inefficient and inelegant.  The following example illustrates my approach, which involves creating a new variable and sorting the data in each iteration.

```
sysuse auto
gen obs_id = _n

foreach i of numlist 1/74{
   *Create variable to get observation to row 1
   gen temp = 1 if obs_id == `i'
   sort temp

   *Extract information
   local w = weight[1]
   local ma = make[1]

   *Do something with the macros
   drop temp
}
```

Sometimes I do this with all numeric variables, so I use

```
sum weight if obs_id == `i'
local w = r(mean)
```

inside the loop instead, which is somewhat more efficient.

But is there a way to save information from a variable in a more sensible way than this?

**Edited to add:**
As William's answer suggested, my intention *was* to sort through a subset of observations, with the subset identified by some dummy variable (i.e. treat = 1).  But even this can be dealt with via William's basic logic, as follows:

```
sysuse auto
set seed 1234
gen random = uniform()
gen treat = 0
replace treat = 1 if random > 0.7

sum treat if treat == 1
local n = r(N)

bysort treat: gen counter = _n if treat == 1
sort counter

foreach i of numlist 1/`n'{
   local w = weight[`i']
   local ma = make[`i']
   display `"treated unit `i' - `w' `ma' "'
}
```

Comment: I seldom meet a situation I have to loop through observations. I can do most of cumbersome works using `by variable: egen`. For example, you can get means, sums, counts, etc., of a variable for each value of another variable. You can also use `mkmat` and `svmat` to create a matrix from a variable, vice versa, and then use matrix operators.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need a loop even for your edited problem. Given a binary variable `treat` created somehow, your code is essentially equivalent to `list weight make if treat == 1` plus some repeated text.  If the counter is important, you can `generate` that separately and add to the `list`, but even then local macros and loops are entirely dispensable here. I am guess that you're more familiar with languages that do require loops, but in Stata they're often not needed for basic tasks.

Comment: @Nick, my actual use is a little more complicated than simply listing a bunch of values, but I wanted to keep it simple.  That's why, in my original example, all I said was "do something with the macros."  In the interest of not distracting from the core of my question, I simplified the example dramatically so that I could use the shipped auto dataset, not require readers to install user-written commands, and not explain the logic of 30+ lines of code within the loop, when those things were not actually necessary for my question..

Comment: That's all fine by me. As far as the forum is concerned, I'd assert that we have yet to see a convincing example where the approach was a good idea -- and I have yet to understand quite what the problem is. If you've learned from the thread, excellent, but I'd be surprised if the thread was of use to others. It all hinges on an implication that the real example is much more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example processes every row in your dataset. Assuming that is what you want to do with your real data (but I suspect you actually want to process the observations for a small list of values of obs_id) the following accomplishes this more directly.

```
sysuse auto, clear
forvalues i = 1/`= _N' {
    local w = weight[`i']
    local ma = make[`i']
    display `"observation `i' - `w' `ma' "'
}
```

And this can be further simplified to

```
sysuse auto, clear
forvalues i = 1/`= _N' {
    display `"observation `i' - `= weight[`i']' `=make[`i']' "'
    }
```

Comment: To add to William's helpful answer, let me stress that you don't need the variable `temp` at all. In fact you don't need any loop at all. `list weight make` is essentially equivalent here.

Comment: @William, you're right that I intended to loop through a subset of observations. But thinking through this, I couldn't come up with a scenario where your solution (going through all obs) or my edited solution (going through a subset) would not work.  Thanks for helping clarify my thinking!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to underline my comment that the OP's loop is entirely avoidable.

(If it's somehow desirable to see the text `treated unit` again and again, then `generate text = "treated unit"` and include it in the `list`.)

```
sysuse auto, clear 
set seed 1234
gen random = uniform()
gen treat = 0
replace treat = 1 if random > 0.7
sum treat if treat == 1
local n = r(N)
bysort treat: gen counter = _n if treat == 1
sort counter

* OP's method 

foreach i of numlist 1/`n'{
   local w = weight[`i']
   local ma = make[`i']
   display `"treated unit `i' - `w' `ma' "'
}

treated unit 1 - 3670 Buick LeSabre 
treated unit 2 - 4330 Cad. Deville 
treated unit 3 - 3400 Buick Skylark 
treated unit 4 - 3180 Chev. Malibu 
treated unit 5 - 2930 AMC Concord 
treated unit 6 - 2690 Pont. Sunbird 
treated unit 7 - 3210 Pont. Grand Prix 
treated unit 8 - 2200 Plym. Horizon 
treated unit 9 - 2070 Audi Fox 
treated unit 10 - 2640 AMC Spirit 
treated unit 11 - 3720 Merc. Marquis 
treated unit 12 - 2110 Chev. Chevette 
treated unit 13 - 3690 Olds Delta 88 
treated unit 14 - 3600 Dodge Magnum 
treated unit 15 - 4060 Merc. Cougar 
treated unit 16 - 3420 Pont. Phoenix 
treated unit 17 - 3260 Plym. Arrow 
treated unit 18 - 2130 Fiat Strada 
treated unit 19 - 3200 Pont. Le Mans 
treated unit 20 - 2410 Toyota Celica 
treated unit 21 - 2670 Toyota Corona 
treated unit 22 - 2230 Buick Opel 
treated unit 23 - 3250 Buick Century 
treated unit 24 - 1800 Plym. Champ 
treated unit 25 - 2730 Olds Starfire 
treated unit 26 - 3280 Buick Regal 
treated unit 27 - 1800 Ford Fiesta 
treated unit 28 - 1830 Renault Le Car 

* alternative 

list weight make if treat 

     +---------------------------+
     | weight   make             |
     |---------------------------|
  1. |  3,670   Buick LeSabre    |
  2. |  4,330   Cad. Deville     |
  3. |  3,400   Buick Skylark    |
  4. |  3,180   Chev. Malibu     |
  5. |  2,930   AMC Concord      |
     |---------------------------|
  6. |  2,690   Pont. Sunbird    |
  7. |  3,210   Pont. Grand Prix |
  8. |  2,200   Plym. Horizon    |
  9. |  2,070   Audi Fox         |
 10. |  2,640   AMC Spirit       |
     |---------------------------|
 11. |  3,720   Merc. Marquis    |
 12. |  2,110   Chev. Chevette   |
 13. |  3,690   Olds Delta 88    |
 14. |  3,600   Dodge Magnum     |
 15. |  4,060   Merc. Cougar     |
     |---------------------------|
 16. |  3,420   Pont. Phoenix    |
 17. |  3,260   Plym. Arrow      |
 18. |  2,130   Fiat Strada      |
 19. |  3,200   Pont. Le Mans    |
 20. |  2,410   Toyota Celica    |
     |---------------------------|
 21. |  2,670   Toyota Corona    |
 22. |  2,230   Buick Opel       |
 23. |  3,250   Buick Century    |
 24. |  1,800   Plym. Champ      |
 25. |  2,730   Olds Starfire    |
     |---------------------------|
 26. |  3,280   Buick Regal      |
 27. |  1,800   Ford Fiesta      |
 28. |  1,830   Renault Le Car   |
     +---------------------------+
```

Naturally I am happy to believe that this toy problem is proxy for the OP's real problem, but I can't see any implication that the technique used is good programming.